# Jersey SecurityContext.isUserInRole always false when running on Jetty Embedded

Tags: jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to use embedded JettyHttpContainer with Jersey. I use BasicAuthenticator and everything seems to be working:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@PermitAll
public Response getData(@Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    if (securityContext.isUserInRole(Roles.ADMIN)) {
       do something...
```

The problem is, that `securityContext.isUserInRole(Request)` is always false and looking at the source, it is obvious why:

In [JettyHttpContainer:214](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.14/containers/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jetty/JettyHttpContainer.java#L214) ...

```java
private SecurityContext getSecurityContext(final Request request) {
    return new SecurityContext() {

        @Override
        public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
            return false;
        }
```

Does anybody have idea how to use JettyHttpContainer with Jersey SecurityContext properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. I've reported it against Jersey. See https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2750